# How to set the border to be the same size as the picture

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to mage a site with a filter option, so I was thinking to have the filters on the left side, and the items on the right side.

I made a scrollable div for the items, and the border isn't the same size as the picture, that goes for all of them, it is supposed to look something like in the picture shown. I haven't made the script yet, but here is my code:

[image]

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>

  <style>
    #vezivanje {
      background-color: hotpink;
      height: 80px;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      border-top-left-radius: 20px;
      border-top-right-radius: 20px;
      font-size: 20px;
    }
    
    img {
      height: auto;
      max-width: 80%;
    }
    
    #filter {
      position: fixed;
      width: 300px;
      height: 900px;
      border-right: solid;
      border-color: #9f2b68;
      border-right-width: 2px;
      padding-left: 15px;
      padding-top: 30px;
      margin: 10px;
    }
    
    #container {
      position: relative;
      display: grid;
      float: right;
      overflow: scroll;
      width: 1560px;
      height: 850px;
      margin: 10px;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
      grid-gap: 1vh;
    }
    
    .item {
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: #9f2b68;
      margin: 10px;
      border-width: 2px;
    }
    
     ::-webkit-scrollbar {
      display: none;
    }
    
    body {
      background-color: #e2e3e3;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="sve">
    <div id="vezivanje">
      <span class="upustvo">
            <a style="text-decoration:none"><span style="color:white;font-weight:bold">Domaci zadatak</span></a>
      </span>
    </div>

    <div id="filter">
      <div id="uzrast">
        <h2>Uzrast:</h2>
        <p><input type="radio">0+</p>
        <p><input type="radio">3+</p>
        <p><input type="radio">6+</p>
        <p><input type="radio">10+</p>
      </div>

      <div id="cena">
        <h2>Cena:</h2>
        <p>0<input type="range">10.000</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="container"></div>
  </div>
  <script>
    //--------------------------

    let container = document.querySelector("#container");
    let igracke = [];

    function igrackeinfo(slika, godine, cena) {
      this.slika = slika;
      this.godine = godine;
      this.cena = cena;
    };
    igracke.push(new igrackeinfo("https://yekupi.blob.core.windows.net/ekupirs/1200Wx1200H/EK000359292_1.image", "0+", "2000 RSD"));
    igracke.push(new igrackeinfo("https://poklonizabebu.rs/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/Muzicka-igracka-kuca-Brown-2.jpg", "0+", "1500 RSD"));
    igracke.push(new igrackeinfo("https://pertinitoys.com/fajlovi/product/master-wheels-trotinet-p-0282-master-wheels-web-s_5f3fb5d70b71e.jpg", "3+", "1500 RSD"));
    igracke.push(new igrackeinfo("https://www.lego.com/cdn/cs/set/assets/blt70237dec0eef084a/10696.jpg?fit=bounds&format=jpg&quality=80&width=1600&height=1600&dpr=1", "3+", "5000 RSD"));
    igracke.push(new igrackeinfo("https://img.goglasi.com/img/225234594", "3+", "3000 RSD"));
    igracke.push(new igrackeinfo("https://www.bcgroup-online.com/upload/m/84401-lego-duplo-10915-kamion-sa-slovima-abecede.jpg", "3+", "2000 RSD"));
    igracke.push(new igrackeinfo("https://www.decjisajt.rs/files/watermark/files/thumbs/files/images/product/2018/01/29/thumbs_1200/thumbs_w/drvena-muzicka-igracka-velika-gitara-91701_1200_1200px_w.jpg", "3+", "9000 RSD"));

    igracke.forEach(t => {
      container.innerHTML += "<div class = 'item'><img src = " + t.slika + ">" +
        "<p>" + t.godine + " " + t.cena + "</p>"
      "</div>"
    })
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The `max-width` of your images is set to 80% so there will always be a 20% gap. Try using 100%. Plus, as a suggestion: try adding a screenshot of your result as well (not just the image of your goal), instead of just the code. This will help to explain what your problem is.

Answer (score 1):

The `max-width` of your images is set to 80% so there will always be a `20%` gap. [`@ishiro`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19009064/ishiro), But it is a solution to be as you want it to be.

1. Class `.item` set `width: 80%`.
2. Tag `img` set `max-width: 100%`.

This way the 20% space disappears and the border will stick to the image without changing the image size.

```js
//--------------------------

let container = document.querySelector("#container");
let igracke = [];

function igrackeinfo(slika, godine, cena) {
  this.slika = slika;
  this.godine = godine;
  this.cena = cena;
}
igracke.push(
  new igrackeinfo(
    "https://yekupi.blob.core.windows.net/ekupirs/1200Wx1200H/EK000359292_1.image",
    "0+",
    "2000 RSD"
  )
);
igracke.push(
  new igrackeinfo(
    "https://poklonizabebu.rs/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/Muzicka-igracka-kuca-Brown-2.jpg",
    "0+",
    "1500 RSD"
  )
);
igracke.push(
  new igrackeinfo(
    "https://pertinitoys.com/fajlovi/product/master-wheels-trotinet-p-0282-master-wheels-web-s_5f3fb5d70b71e.jpg",
    "3+",
    "1500 RSD"
  )
);
igracke.push(
  new igrackeinfo(
    "https://www.lego.com/cdn/cs/set/assets/blt70237dec0eef084a/10696.jpg?fit=bounds&format=jpg&quality=80&width=1600&height=1600&dpr=1",
    "3+",
    "5000 RSD"
  )
);
igracke.push(
  new igrackeinfo("https://img.goglasi.com/img/225234594", "3+", "3000 RSD")
);
igracke.push(
  new igrackeinfo(
    "https://www.bcgroup-online.com/upload/m/84401-lego-duplo-10915-kamion-sa-slovima-abecede.jpg",
    "3+",
    "2000 RSD"
  )
);
igracke.push(
  new igrackeinfo(
    "https://www.decjisajt.rs/files/watermark/files/thumbs/files/images/product/2018/01/29/thumbs_1200/thumbs_w/drvena-muzicka-igracka-velika-gitara-91701_1200_1200px_w.jpg",
    "3+",
    "9000 RSD"
  )
);

igracke.forEach((t) => {
  container.innerHTML +=
    "<div class = 'item'><img src = " +
    t.slika +
    ">" +
    "<p>" +
    t.godine +
    " " +
    t.cena +
    "</p>";
  ("</div>");
});
```

```css
#vezivanje {
  background-color: hotpink;
  height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#filter {
  position: fixed;
  width: 300px;
  height: 900px;
  border-right: solid;
  border-color: #9f2b68;
  border-right-width: 2px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  margin: 10px;
}

#container {
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  float: right;
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 1560px;
  height: 850px;
  margin: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 1vh;
}

.item {
  width: 80%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #9f2b68;
  margin: 10px;
  border-width: 2px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

body {
  background-color: #e2e3e3;
}
```

```html
<div id="sve">
  <div id="vezivanje">
    <span class="upustvo">
      <a style="text-decoration:none"><span style="color:white;font-weight:bold">Domaci zadatak</span></a>
    </span>
  </div>

  <div id="filter">
    <div id="uzrast">
      <h2>Uzrast:</h2>
      <p><input type="radio">0+</p>
      <p><input type="radio">3+</p>
      <p><input type="radio">6+</p>
      <p><input type="radio">10+</p>
    </div>

    <div id="cena">
      <h2>Cena:</h2>
      <p>0<input type="range">10.000</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="container"></div>
</div>
```